# Interfering Keylisteners in java

Tags: java, swing, jtree, keylistener, swingx

I have a JXTree and I'd like to add searching to it this way:
As the user types, the model returns the matching elements of the tree and selects the first one of the set in the tree's view. 
The problem is, that by default the JXTree has an other keylistener, that selects an element starting with the currently typed letter.
Sometimes the native listener fires last making the outcome wrong. What can be done to prevent this behavior? I don't want to remove the inherent listener because it has arrow based navigation... (Which I have to reimplement.)
I've already read this: [Is the order in which KeyListeners will be called guaranteed?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5274172/is-the-order-in-which-keylisteners-will-be-called-guaranteed), but I don't think that I can create the proposed listener wrapper without great effort, since BasicTreeUI's Handler class is private.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's not a feature of JXTree but JTree. Overriding JTree#getNextMatch() to always return null should disable the JTree selection on key press.

Comment: I've just made a quick try, but this really seems to work. Thanks!